# MVC calling external API in View and adding authentication header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a MVC application which is hosted on a web role in the Azure Cloud Service. What I am trying to do is to send a API post request after the user push a button. I have this multipart form in my view and, instead of calling a controller, I just want to post this data to an external API which is specific in the action attribute. The code is shown below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @action = "http://localhost:55637/api/dataingestion/upload" }))
{
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
        <input type="text" name="filePath" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <button>Upload</button>
    </div>
}
```

And the external API is like this

Because that API is protected by the Azure Active Directory, I need to put the authentication token in the header of the request. The token is acquired in one controller method and stored in the TempData dictionary as shown below.

My question is how can I pass this token to the View and when the View try to post the multipart form data, how can I add the token to the header of the request?

```
public ActionResult Authenticate()
    {

        Uri redirectURI = new Uri(redirectURL);

        try
        {
            AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireToken(resourceID, clientID, redirectURI);
            string type = ar.AccessTokenType;
            string token = ar.AccessToken;
            TempData["token"] = token;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //If user cancel the login then stay at home page
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("UploadViwe");

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the token to the View by using ViewBag/ModelBinding and bind it to HiddenFields inside your page - Let me know if you need more help here.

Once the token is available on the page, you need to intercept the call by adding an event listener before the file upload, this can be done using jquery file post https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/, jquery file upload gives a bunch of callback options as mentioned here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options

Once you're on the listener you can add custom headers as mentioned in the below example.

```js
$('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
  $.ajax({
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "[token here]");
  }
```

Or this example

```js
$('#upload_btn').fileupload({
    singleFileUploads: true,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, data) {
        var file = data.files[0];
        xhr.setRequestHeader('[Header name]', '[Header Value]');
    },
});
```